# Stage customer data to Snowflake

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to import csv files into our Snowflake account uploaded by our customer.

The exact import part can be done by COPY INTO command, but googling around I haven't found an exact solution, how can I transfer data from customer's machine to SF's stage (external stage, in our case AWS S3).

If possible, I would like to avoid to load our servers with the task to ingress a data from a POST request & forward it to SF stage.

I'm thinking about a solution to generate OAuth token for the customer (customer access our API via authenticated session) allowing he / she to PUT csv file only.

As this seems a bit dangerous, I would ask, if anybody here have experience how to stage (possible large: few GB) CSV files into SF, even OAuth would be the right choose.

Thank you

Comment: Hi - your question doesn't seem to be directly related to Snowflake (as you know how to do the Snowflake part of the process i.e. the COPY INTO), you appear to be asking how to load files into S3? If that's the case then why not have a specific bucket for this and give your customer permissions to upload files to this bucket? If the customer can't/won't do this then they'll need to get the files to you by whatever process you agree on and then you upload them to S3

Comment: Hi - Actually, I would like to avoid AWS S3, as it requires our dev effort to maintain it, but I would prefer to use Snowflake's internal stage.
The question really wants to point into two aspect: how can I avoid to utilize our backend infrastructure to participate in the data transfer between customer's machine and Snowflake
The other aspect is the security, as I cannot give peer customer permission to our Snowflake account

Comment: If you want to use an internal stage then you would need to get the customer files into a local file system and then run the PUT command. How you do the first step is up to you to decide between you and your customer. Bear in mind that asking for recommendations for tools, if that’s part of your question, is off topic for this forum

Comment: As @NickW Mentioned you would need to get the customer data file into local file system and then run put command. Otherwise user can put the file in any linux machine and run the put command regular interval to load into snowflake internal stage